# Python Celery : ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

Tags: python, flask, celery, amqp, pika

I'm trying to publish a message to Celery via RabbitMQ using the python library [Pika](https://github.com/pika/pika)

The message hits RabbitMQ but blows up when Celery handles it. I have no issues when I implement the same concept using .Net or Php, but I just can't seem to get it to work using python.

**Connect to RabbitMQ**

```
 connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
 channel = connection.channel()
```

**Publishing a message:**

```
def sendMsg():
    #generate a unique ID
    rd = random.Random()
    rd.seed(0)
    id = uuid.UUID(int=rd.getrandbits(128))
    msg = '{"msg":"What if i fall? but son, what if you fly"}'
    hrds = {'task': 'task.hello', 'id':str(id)}
    properties = pika.BasicProperties(content_type='application/json',headers= hrds)
    channel.basic_publish(exchange='celery',routing_key='celery',body=msg,properties=properties)
```

**Celery task handler**

```
@app.task
def hello(msg):
   print("Your msg is: "+msg)
```

**Celery Error:**

```
    [2018-09-14 06:44:01,091: ERROR/MainProcess] Pool callback raised exception: ValueError('too many values to unpack (expected 3)',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/devops/Documents/celery/workers/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 42, in __get__
    return obj.__dict__[self.__name__]
KeyError: 'chord'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/devops/Documents/celery/workers/lib/python3.6/site-packages/billiard/pool.py",
> line 1747, in safe_apply_callback
>     fun(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/devops/Documents/celery/workers/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/request.py",
> line 366, in on_failure
>     self.id, exc, request=self, store_result=self.store_errors,   File "/home/devops/Documents/celery/workers/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py",
> line 157, in mark_as_failure
>     if request.chord:   File "/home/devops/Documents/celery/workers/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py",
> line 44, in __get__
>     value = obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = self.__get(obj)   File "/home/devops/Documents/celery/workers/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/request.py",
> line 485, in chord
>     _, _, embed = self._payload ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

> Environment: Linux, Python: 3.6.5,  Pika: 0.12.0

Comment: The error in your question header is a *downstream* error: it is coming from an `except` statement that isn't robust enough. The real error is `KeyError: 'chord'` which means the code was expecting a dict to have a key value of `'chord'` that was not there.

Comment: @BoarGules thank you for taking your time to reply. I understand better now. But how do I trace the error, I'm pretty sure I followed the documentation guides. Also, could you recommend a different python library. I'm really pulling my hair out here. been on it for hours :D

Comment: @FrankDupree why are you not using Celery to schedule the task? E.g. : `hello.delay("Test message")`

Comment: @ChirilaAlexandru  I'm beginning to ask myself the same question. It's a flask application, thought i'd abstract the implementation using industry standards, but i'm pretty sure this is a bug.

Anyway, I'll be going with you suggestion, thanks.

Comment: @FrankDupree did issue got resolved ?

Comment: Came across the same issue when publishing between 2 services. Realized it was not a code error but that the publisher was using celery version 5 but the consumer had celery version 4. After upgrading 4 to 5 my issue was resolved.